# How to keep custom shapes on slide independent of the aspect ratio in PowerPoint C# VSTO?

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint-2010

I have some custom text-boxes and an image on PowerPoint slide created programmatically in C# VSTO. While everything looks nice in 4:3 aspect ratio, the text-boxes stick together (in other words, the distance between them gets diminished) as soon as I change the aspect ratio to 16:9. I want to keep the separation between the text-boxes same irrespective of the aspect ratio selected for the slide.

I tried with the LockAspectRatio property of the shapes, but I guess I am missing something.

Edit:-> Also, with 16:9 aspect ratio selected, when I add another custom slide(on click of a custom button) the textboxes and other shapes move out of the slide. Which should not happen and the shapes should readjust themselves to fit inside the selected size.

Can anyone help me we this.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for code to position the shapes once you've described the rules that govern how they should be positioned, or are you asking for an explanation of the rules?

Comment: Yes I am asking for any code to position the shapes to a fixed co-ordinates on the slide, and that the shapes should be able to get arranged as per the selected Aspect Ratio. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.  But you'd essentially need to define a 4:3 window within the 16x9 slide and adjust each shape's height and width properties to move it into that window.

Comment: Hi Steve, could you suggest any event on which to resize the shapes.
I am looking for something to capture the aspect ratio or orientation
change event.

Comment: I have edited the Question slightly to make the problem a bit clearer.

Comment: There's no event triggered when the slide/page size changes; you might have to work with the selection change event instead. As to the other question and w/o any example to look at, my guess is that your master placeholders are off the slide.

Comment: Hi Steve! I was able to implement it in a rather crude way I guess,
I have taken height and width multipliers as float variables. I am getting their values on run time depending on the slide height and width as follows:

    heightMultiplier = (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight) / 540;
            
widthMultiplier = (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth) / 720;

These values i am multiplying with the shape co-ordinates on slide as well as with their heights and widths so that they maintain both their position and shape.